# Asymptotic curves

Tags: differential-geometry

So I know that asymptotic curves are the ones where the acceleration of the curve doesn't have a normal component, but instead lays on the plane tangent to the surface in each point. So that is: 
$$\ddot{\gamma}(t)\cdot \textbf{N}_{\gamma(t)}=0$$
Now I have to prove that from the expression above we deduce this:
$$\mathcal{F}_{\gamma(t)}(\dot{\gamma}(t)) \cdot \dot{\gamma}(t)=0$$
How can I do this?

Comment: First, you shouldn't assume that everyone knows your notation, although those of us who are differential geometers can deduce what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**: As happens frequently in differential geometry, differentiate the equation
$$\mathbf N_{\gamma(t)}\cdot\dot\gamma(t) = 0$$
(which holds for all $t$).